# How to get public reach by facebook-graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to get public reach and send a requests to the Facebook graph api. This is my request:

```
page_id/insights?metric=page_impressions&period=day&since=1557654435&until=1557740835&access_token=token
```

In response I get filed `data` with empty list.

Could you tell me with with what it can be related?

Comment: Most likely you’re missing `read_insights` permission?

Comment: @04FS, could you show example with `read_insights`. 
To be honest I didn't see `read_insights` in documentation.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-read_insights

Comment: O, ty. So, I need to add permissions for my app?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: ty for your help